# Get numeric value from a div that changes based on inputs combined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a td:

```
   <td class="floatingTermsVehicle totalNetVehicle bold">$28,435</td>
```

That is displaying the sum of two inputs:

```
                <label for="estimatedTaxesAndFees" class="form-control-label etfl">Estimated Taxes and Fees</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="estimatedTaxesAndFees" placeholder="$0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onBlur="addCommas(this)"/>
```

Based on this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function () {
    $("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice,#estimatedTaxesAndFees", function () {
        updateTotalNetVehicle();
    });
    var updateTotalNetVehicle = function () {
        var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
        var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
        var sum = input1 + input2;
        $('.totalNetVehicle').text('$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    };
   });
});
```

How could I get the numeric value of what is being displayed in the td that changes based on the above equation which is then populating the totalNetVehicle class?

Comment: Off-topic: when you add the blur event handler, use `updateTotalNetVehicle` instead of `function () { updateTotalNetVehicle(); }`

Comment: Why can’t you grab the sum right there where it is calculated …?

Comment: Which type of `error` you are getting or what you expected?

Comment: It's not an error per se... what I am doing is displaying the total from the two inputs as the width and updating the css that is displayed based on the calculations of the two inputs combined.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var text = $.trim($('.totalNetVehicle').text());
var value = +text.substring(1) || 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your `sum` variable outside:

```
var sum,
    updateTotalNetVehicle = function () {
        var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0,
            input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
        sum = input1 + input2;
        $('.totalNetVehicle')
            .text('$' + sum.toFixed(2)
            .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    };
```

And then you only need to use `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use substring(1) to get the number as string.
2. replace ',' in your number with '' using .search()
   or
   look for the , in the substring and create two substrings on the left and right of it. Then join them.
3. Use parseInt() to get the integer value. Now you can use arithematic on it